# Error: Could not find or load main class Account\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

1. I downloaded elasticsearch-7.16.3
2. Extracted it into `C:\Softwares\elasticsearch-7.16.3`
3. I get the following error when I run bin\elasticsearch.bat

> ```
> C:\Softwares\elasticsearch-7.16.3>bin\elasticsearch.bat
> Error: Could not find or load main class Account\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Account\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch
>
> C:\Softwares\elasticsearch-7.16.3>
> ```

I am running on Windows 10. What am I doing wrong here?